# How to add a method for active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would want to use my method getScheduleFixed() on a Active Record Istance

```
ps = ProgramSchedule.all
ps.getScheduleFixed
```

the important fact is how to access to "ps" array (active record) on my method declaration

```
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  def getScheduleFixed

    array = (HERE ARRAY RETURNED BY ACTIVE RECORD)

    # some stuff...

    return array

  end
end
```

Comment: `.all` returns an array, not ActiveRecord instance. Can you do `ProgramSchedule.getScheduleFixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up here.

**1)** There are **(instance) methods** that you can use on a single ActiveRecord object.

```
# Returns an ARRAY with all programschedule instances
all_ps = ProgramSchedule.all

# You can now iterate over over the array
all_ps.each do |ps|
  # in here you can call the instance method on the actual model instance
  ps.instance_method
end

# Definition of this method in app/models/program_schedule.rb
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  def instance_method
    # Foo
  end
end
```

**2)** There are **class methods** that you can run on the ActiveRecord model itself.

```
ProgramSchedule.class_method

# Definition of this method in app/models/program_schedule.rb
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.class_method
    # Bar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ProgramSchedule.all`, you get an `Array`, not an instance of `ProgramSchedule`.

If your method will be called with all the records at all times, you can use a class method like this one :

```
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.getAllScheduleFixed
    array = ProgramSchedule.all # or self.class.all could be used if you subclass this class
    #some stuff
  end
end
```

If you need to work with only a subset of ProgramSchedule's, that is conditions, you will need to pass conditions to this class method, or to directly pass the array of results to some class method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use scope for this:

```
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :fixed, { all.map(&:getScheduleFixed) }

end
```

or

```
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.fixed
    all.map(&:getScheduleFixed)
  end

end
```

Now you just need to call `ProgramSchedule.fixed`. Both these methods can be chained on other scopes such as `ProgramSchedule.latest.fixed`. See more details [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def getScheduleFixed
    array = User.all.map(&:name)
    return array
  end
```